# Help on get the information about mavic3

Tags: dji

I search on dji website about the mavic 3 spaces and there few things that I don’t understand

1. What is the real range of the mavic 3 on the spaces write max fly distance is 30km but the range is 15 km
2. What is the difference between  Transmitter Power (EIRP) to Transmission Power (EIRP)?

3.The reciver and the transmitter on the drone and on the controller is the same?

3. I know the on mavic 3 there 4 antennas 2t4r I want  get more information about them (what is the gain and so on)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Range is how far away the drone can go whereas fly distance is the total distance the drone can fly.  Fly distance is thus 30km (twice 15km) because in order to have a range of 15 km the drone has to be able to go out 15 km and come back 15 km.
2. From basic reading on the subject (check out these wikipedia pages: [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Radio_transmission_power), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmitter_power_output)), it appears that they are relatively synonymous.  It could be that there are slight technical differences (for instance transmitter power appears to refer specifically to the power the transmitter outputs, whereas transmission power seems to figure in the ability of the drone to receive the power as well).
3. I think you'd probably be better to open a separate question with a bit more detail on exactly what information you're looking for.

---

Hope it helps!